# Django | Static Files

Tags: django

Не понимаю почему не подгружаются статические файлы в проекте:

**settings.py**

```
...

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main_site', 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

...
```

**Структура проекта**

```
.
├── config
├── images
├── main_site
    ├── migrations
    ├── static
    └── templates
└── venv
```

*UPD:*

1. `python3 manage.py collectstatic` не помог.
2. `MEDIA_ROOT` тоже не работает. Изображений нет.
3. [Не помогает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809416/django-static-files-404)

Comment: Вы не забыли настроить веб-сервер, который будет заниматься раздачей ваших STATIC_ROOT и MEDIA_ROOT?

Comment: @andreymal, в каком смысле? На `flask` все было проще.

Comment: В том смысле, что Django не занимается раздачей статических файлов, это не входит в задачи веб-фреймворка. Раздачей статических файлов должен заниматься веб-сервер, и к flask это кстати тоже касается

Comment: @andreymal, я понимаю к чему вы клоните. Ладно, напишу веб серв.

Comment: Зачем писать, возьмите готовый и проверенный временем nginx

Comment: @andreymal, хотел сказать: "пойду конфиги искать под нгинкс"

Comment: А ещё STATIC_ROOT не должен указывать внутрь Django-приложений. Это каталог, в который команда collectstatic будет складывать файлы из Django-приложений, а складывание файлов в самого себя является рекурсивным абсурдом. Кроме того, команда collectstatic с опцией `--delete` может удалять файлы, а вы скорее всего не хотите удалять файлы из Django-приложений